# How to insert multiple complex lines containing spaces, pipes, grep and sed commands before pattern

Tags: sed

The goal is to insert the following complex lines before a specific pattern in a file:

```
NDPI_VERSION_SHORT=$(cat Makefile | grep -P "^NDPI_VERSION_SHORT = " | sed -E 's|^NDPI_VERSION_SHORT = (.*)$|\1|g') \
NDPI_VERSION_SHORT=${NDPI_VERSION_SHORT//[[:space:]]/} \
NDPI_MAJOR=$(cat Makefile | grep -P "^NDPI_MAJOR = " | sed -E 's|^NDPI_MAJOR = (.*)$|\1|g') \
NDPI_MAJOR=${NDPI_MAJOR//[[:space:]]/}
```

I unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
sed -i '/pattern/i \
NDPI_VERSION_SHORT=$(cat Makefile | grep -P "^NDPI_VERSION_SHORT = " | sed -E \'s|^NDPI_VERSION_SHORT = (.*)$|\1|g\') \
NDPI_VERSION_SHORT=${NDPI_VERSION_SHORT\/\/[[:space:]]\/} \
NDPI_MAJOR=$(cat Makefile | grep -P "^NDPI_MAJOR = " | sed -E \'s|^NDPI_MAJOR = (.*)$|\1|g\') \
NDPI_MAJOR=${NDPI_MAJOR\/\/[[:space:]]\/}' file

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I also tried to quote all inserted lines leading to the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's better to use file instead, or use other tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed "/pattern/i \
NDPI_VERSION_SHORT=\$\(cat Makefile | grep -P \"^NDPI_VERSION_SHORT = \" | sed -E 's|^NDPI_VERSION_SHORT = \(.*\)\$|\\\1|g'\) \\\ \n\
NDPI_VERSION_SHORT=\${NDPI_VERSION_SHORT//[[:space:]]/} \\\ \n\
NDPI_MAJOR=\$\(cat Makefile | grep -P \"^NDPI_MAJOR = \" | sed -E 's|^NDPI_MAJOR = \(.*\)\$|\\\1|g'\) \\\ \n\
NDPI_MAJOR=\${NDPI_MAJOR//[[:space:]]/}" file
```

The problem is the single quote within the inserted text, which will end the sed script and which cannot be escaped. You can use single quotes, though, if you use double quotes to enclose the script. This, however, means you'll need to escape quite a lot of things in your text: The `$`, `"`, `(`, `)`. Since the shell itself uses up a backslash for escaping, you need to write `\\\` where you have a `\`. And the line break is achieved via a `\n`. Note that the `/` does not need to be escaped since sed does not use it as delimiter here.